# Celery send_task and retry on exception

Tags: celery, django-celery, celery-task

I want to `retry` ([official doc](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#retrying)) a task when it raises an exception. Celery allows this by using the `retry` in form of `self.retry(...)`

Now, i can't figure out how to user `self` since i've a function without any class.

My code is this

```
.. imports ...
app = Celery('elasticcelery')
@app.task(name='rm_doc')
def rm_doc(schema_id, id):
    es = Elasticsearch(es_ip)
    try:
        res = es.delete(schema_id, 'doc', id)
    except NotFoundError as e:
        <here goes the retry>
```

and it's called from another service in this way:

```
app_celery = Celery('celeryelastic')
                app_celery.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
                app_celery.send_task('rm_doc', kwargs={"schema_id": schema_id, "id": document_id}, )
```

now, I should add the `self.retry` but there's no `self` in my method.

How should I proceed?

PS: I tried adding `self` as parmeter, but  this fails since there's no mapping when the task is called the first time from the remote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot `bind=True` in the annotation of the method, now I can add `self`.